# Azure connectivity issue with VPN

Tags: azure, ip, vpn, connectivity, whitelist

I am having issues with my Azure environment. Trying to test a connection to the storage account, with VPN logged in. However, I want to see why the removal of the home IP address is preventing access, even when I am logged into VPN. I am still learning more about Azure and cloud, any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

So, what I did so far:

1. I tried testing connectivity with the IPs that are whitelisted, while not logged into the VPN--this was fine as I could still connect.
2. To confirm this, I then tried to remove the selected IPs from the whitelist and was able to confirm that I could not access the table storage. All of this is still while not logged into the VPN.
3. I attempted a login to the VPN, but saw that I can't connect to it like I was able to when I wasn't logged in.
4. I tried switching the destination port to wildcard, didn't work. I tried also switching to specific ports, still didn't work.
5. I adjusted the priority rule so that way it has the top priority, still not able to connect.
6. I was uncertain if the NSG I had setup was working, so I placed my IP into the address list, still was not working. Not sure if the NSG is working correctly?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

*You can troubleshoot the VPN connectivity to check the issues.*

- *Login to Azure Portal and go to **Network Watcher***
- *Once network watcher is opened go to **VPN troubleshoot***
- *Then select your storage account and container and click on **start troubleshooting** that will give you the errors.*
- *Under the **Status** and **Action** you could find the reason.*

[image]

- *Same way you can even check the **NSG diagnostics***

[image]

Also check these VPN troubleshoot documents provided by Microsoft.

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/tutorial-site-to-site-portal
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-stack/user/site-to-site?view=azs-2108&tabs=az